# How to transform linearlayout background by position

Tags: android

I'm having trouble finding the answer to this question.

I want to emulate the transformation of an image inside an `ImageView` e.g.

```
image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
animationSlideInLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
image1.startAnimation(animationSlideInLeft);
```

But that's not what I want exactly. Instead, I want to transform a `drawable` set as a `linear layout` background.

```
linearLayout.setBackground(drawable);
```

How can I transform the `drawable` and make it move from left to right inside of the LinearLayout?

Comment: Yeah `slide_in_left` is an xml file. It's not a prerequisite though. I just need a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  RelativeLayout or AbsoluteLayout ,put an image (that covers it's parent) in it and then mount current layout of activity.Now if you set animation for that image,it seems that background of your activity animates.
For example suppose this is current layout of your activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now this layout looks like previous layout and you can set animation for image that it's ID is `img1`(it seems as backgr:ound of main layout):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bright_sun" />
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/vg2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Found here: [Android activity - background drawable animated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468425/android-activity-background-drawable-animated)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work for what you're after but have you thought about setting an `ImageView` inside of the `LinearLayout` and making the height and width the same as the `LinearLayout` instead of setting the `LinearLayout` background? You can that animate the `ImageView` like you are doing now and it will give the same result.

Comment: I had thought of that, but then how can I overlay the widgets inside the linear layout over the image view?

Comment: You would have to wrap the `LinearLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`. Place the `ImageView` in the `RelativeLayout` and the rest of your view inside the `LinearLayout`

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, but Sese answered before you with the suggestion to use relative layout. I have upvoted your comments and answers none the less. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I answered before him - check the answered x mins ago. But no worries! Thanks for the up-vote!

Comment: Ah I didn't say about the RelativeLayout until the comments though - got it!